# Popover crash when update value using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover, uipopovercontroller, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I want to make popover on iPhone , I notice when using `.popover` in iPhone it will always show as sheet , but on iPad it will show as popover

so I decide to use UIKit version
everything is working fine until I tap on Button to update the view

it will crash with this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_6HStackGVS_9TupleViewTGVS_6ButtonVS_4Text_S4_GS3_S4______: 0x7fd47b424df0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x7fd47b426200>.
```

My code :

```
struct PopoverViewModifier<PopoverContent>: ViewModifier where PopoverContent: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    let content: () -> PopoverContent

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                Popover(
                    isPresented: self.$isPresented,
                    onDismiss: self.onDismiss,
                    content: self.content
                )
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func popover<Content>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View where Content: View {
        ModifiedContent(
            content: self,
            modifier: PopoverViewModifier(
                isPresented: isPresented,
                onDismiss: onDismiss,
                content: content
            )
        )
    }
}

struct Popover<Content: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self, content: self.content())
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        let host = context.coordinator.host
        if self.isPresented {
            host.preferredContentSize = host.sizeThatFits(in: CGSize(width: Int.max , height: Int.max))
            host.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
            host.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = uiViewController.view
            host.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = uiViewController.view.bounds
            uiViewController.present(host, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            host.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
        let host: UIHostingController<Content>
        private let parent: Popover

        init(parent: Popover, content: Content) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.host = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        }

        func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            self.parent.isPresented = false
            if let onDismiss = self.parent.onDismiss {
                onDismiss()
            }
        }

        func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
            return .none
        }
    }
}
```

How I use it :

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var openChangeFont = false
@State var currentFontSize = 0

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {

        Text("Test")
          
  
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    Text("Popover")
                        .popover(isPresented: $openChangeFont, content: {
                            HStack {
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        currentFontSize += 2
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Increase")
                                })
                                
                                Text("\(currentFontSize)")
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    currentFontSize -= 2

                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Decrease")
                                })

                            }
                    })
                        .onTapGesture {
                            openChangeFont.toggle()
                    }
                }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in `Popover.updateUIViewController` and I think you’ll catch the problem. `updateUIViewController` is called every time the SwiftUI view is updated, which means it may be called when `isPresented` is true *and* you the popover is *already* being presented.

If that’s the issue, then you need to track whether you’re already presenting the popover or not. You’re already implementing `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` so you can use that.

Comment: I tried to change the logic inside `updateUIViewController` by adding `host.viewIfLoaded?.window == nil && self.isPresented`it solve the crash , but every time the view update it will dismiss

Comment: If you added that to your `if-else`, make sure you aren’t falling through to the `else` that dismisses the popover. You basically want two `if` statements: `if host.viewIfLoaded?.window == nil && self.isPresented` then show popover; `if self.isPresented == false` then hide popover.

Comment: currently it won't dismiss , and it won't crash , but it won't update should I pass currentFontSize to UIViewControllerRepresentable or is there other way ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to update, but check out the `Context` that’s passed in to updateUIViewController — it contains all of the SwiftUI environment values, such as font and accent color, so whatever you need is likely in there. If you’re still stuck, I’d suggest posting a new question with your current code.

Comment: Thank you very much ,I figure it out , I add `host.rootView = content()` after `let host = context.coordinator.host` , now everything working fine